# How can I access pagesBatch from Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

This works fine

```sh
curl -vsu ":${pat}" -XGET \
"https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/wiki/wikis/${project}.wiki/pages/20/stats?api-version=6.0-preview.1&pageViewsForDays=3"
```

but the following gives me an **HTTP 401** - using the same *personal access token*:

```sh
curl -vsu ":${pat}" -d '{"top":5}' -XPOST \
"https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/wiki/wikis/${project}.wiki/pagesBatch?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
```

Here are specs for the [former](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/blob/master/specification/wiki/6.0/httpExamples/pageStats/GET_wiki_pageStats.json) and for the [latter](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/blob/master/specification/wiki/6.0/httpExamples/pagesBatch/GET_wiki_pageBatch_WithoutContinuationToken.json).

I am admin of the project in question, so this should not be a permission problem, I suppose. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 401 error response indicates that proper authorization was not provided, so base on the error, you can try to create a new PAT with the scope selected as `full access` and try again.

[image]

I tested this rest api with postman , it works fine. You can also test in postman to see if the problem only occurs when using curl.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works with a full access token. I don't however want to grant full access for this, which is why I (thought I) gave enough permissions, which are these: `Code (Read); Wiki (Read); Work Items (Read)`. But it seems being able to read Wiki is not enough... If you happen to know what specific permission is needed for this, please let me know. Is this documented somewhere?