# How can I call pre-release Rest Apis from an Azure DevOps extension?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

It [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59516510/709537) REST clients for preview versions of the Azure DevOps REST APIs do not get published. So the API is there and [works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59453164/709537), but a REST client is not.

So how can I access e.g. the 6.0 (as of now: preview) feature [`pagesBatch`](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/blob/master/specification/wiki/6.0/httpExamples/pagesBatch/GET_wiki_pageBatch_WithPageViews.json) from an Azure DevOps extension?

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a preview API and not included yet in the SDK you can do a pure HTTP Get/Post Rest API calls with Typescript, for example:

Install:

```
npm install --save request
npm install --save request-promise-native
```

Then in the extension:

```
import * as request from "request-promise-native";

(async () => {

  const url = 'https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/e5e9e01e-801a-47eb-80bb-0ad24f448abe/_apis/wiki/wikis/sampleProjectWiki/pagesBatch';
  const result = await request.post(url, access_token: 'your-pat', body: JSON.stringify({pageViewsForDays: '30', continuationToken: '1', top: '5', 'content_type': 'application/json' }}}) );


 })()
```

Or use another Rest API methods, there are many ways to do it on Typescript.

Comment: Thanks - but don't you then need to provide a PAT (personal access token)? I believe that when an extension uses a RestClient, that will be taken care of. That is why I am shying away from a direct http request.

Comment: You are right, I guess you need to provide a token or to use the user credentials who run the extension.